# How to run on GlassFish in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I am using **IntelliJ**, and I have a J2EE project. I have setted up a local GlassFish server in the IDE, but how can I configure the project to run on that local GlassFish server?

My project uses Java EE's features (such as servlets), but IntelliJ says that those libraries do not exist:

[image]

I can't run my project either:

[image]

***How do I associate my local GlassFish server with the project, and enable the GlassFIsh's library?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the recommended way to create your J2EE project in Intellij?

Follow the guide here: [Getting Started with Java EE 7 and GlassFish 4.0](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Java+EE+7+and+GlassFish+4.0)

Comment: Please edit your answer with a summary of the link, so that it is still useful after the link may die.

Comment: This uses intellij ULTIMATE Editition. How to do it in Community Edition

Comment: @adafrwefsefr Looks like it can't be achieved with the Community Edition - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812906/java-enterprise-doesnt-appear-in-intellij

Answer (score 3):

> I have setted up a local GlassFish server in the IDE, but how can I configure the project to run on that local GlassFish server?

I assume that you did this using **Run > Edit Configurations...** in which a local or remote Glassfish server can be configured. So in the window of Glassfish edit configurations there is a tab named **deployment** in which you can add source(s) to be deployed at the server startup.

[image: deploy at the server startup]

> My project uses Java EE's features (such as servlets), but IntelliJ
>   says that those libraries do not exist:

Go to **File > Project structure** or press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S click to open **Modules > Dependencies** tab press the Add (+) button select **Library...** and there you can find Glassfish and add it as a dependency.

[image: dependencies]