# Java Enterprise doesn't appear in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, server, glassfish

I have problem about importing Java EE glassfish server to my IntelliJ.
I have searched nothing on the web.

When I want to create a new glassfish project, I don't have option for it.

I can't add image cause I don't have reputation for it. I add direct link to image below text.

Screenshots:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears you have a community version of IntelliJ. Tools to support enterprise frameworks, like JavaEE or Grails, are only available in paid version. If need a free JavaEE IDE, I recommend Netbeans,which is similar to IntelliJ but free, or Eclipse, which is also great, but more different

Comment: I have enterprise version and i dont see it. I used to but i upgraded and i dont see any more.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Ultimate version, the accepted answer provides no value.

To enable these project templates to show up you have to enable the [Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-java-ee-application-support.html)

This is bundled with IntelliJ but chances are when you first installed it, this was not selected as one of the resources you wanted, or it was deselected for not knowing what it does.

All you have to do is go to your plugins, click on the 'Installed Tab' and re-enable it. IntelliJ will prompt you to restart

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and switched to the `Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers`. But make sure to download the correct version (the newest stable) otherwise it will give some errors.

Check the below link to download `Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers`

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2023-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers

Furthermore, if you need to use Java EE in the IntelliJ IDEA community edition you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698847/how-to-use-java-ee-intellij-idea-community-edition) answer.