# Java Enterprise doesn't appear in IntelliJ ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I needed to create a java document, and I have inteliji ultimate, but when I create it, it does not appear, I found this link that says that it is necessary to add Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets plugin, but it still does not appear.
is what I am looking for
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2QDU.png)
this way it appears to me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAAWe.png)

thanks :)

I tried the solution on this website, and it didn't work.
[Java Enterprise doesn't appear in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812906/java-enterprise-doesnt-appear-in-intellij)
I also tried to deactivate and reactivate the plugins

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE

Answer (score 1):

The Java EE is now called Jakarta EE.

See post, [*Java EE vs J2EE vs Jakarta EE*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enterprise-evolution#in-transition).